# buttons display over another element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make design like in image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF3dQ.png

But after coding I get some minor errors

- button moves outside of div
- margin doesn't works

to go on with that design there are external libraries but I don't want any external scripts

How can I implement the design with CSS? Can someone help me solve the minor errors I'm stuck with?

### CODE

```css
.div{
    float:left;
    width:22%;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    border: solid 0 #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #CCC;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #CCC;
    position: relative;
}
.div img{
    width:100%;
    height:180px;
}
.div h1{
    font: 500 1.5em Roboto,Arial,Helvetica !important;
}
.div div{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%
}
.div div a{
    width:45%;
    float:right;
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="div">
    <img src="thumb/ufdRX.png"/>
    <h5>WINDOWS</h5>
    <h1>Boot From a CD or USB Drive on Any PC</h1><hr>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a><br>
    </div>     
</div>
<div class="div">
    <img src="dual.png"/>
    <h1>Top Ten Android Application</h1>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a></div>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <img src="dual.png"/>
    <h1>How to take Snapshot in android Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.x</h1>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a></div>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <img src="dual.png"/>
    <h1>10 Programming Languages You Should Learn Right Now</h1>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a></div>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <img src="dual.png"/>
    <h1>12 Effective Home Remedies To Treat Skin Cancer</h1>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a></div>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <img src="dual.png"/>
    <h1>Social networking sites</h1>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a></div>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <img src="dual.png"/>
    <h1>top hotels around world to visit</h1>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a></div>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <img src="dual.png"/>
    <h1>best places you must visit in india</h1>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a></div>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <img src="dual.png"/>
    <h1>worst places you should never visit</h1>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a></div>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <img src="dual.png"/>
    <h1>top ten best mobiles</h1>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: this is caused by the floating elements. Try researching 'clearfix floats' on google...

Comment: Which is the button??is that the Readmore?

Comment: Your positioning absolute `.div .div` and `.div div a`. remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace these codes from the ones in your css (removing absolute positioning):

```
.div div{
    bottom:0;
    width:100%
}
.div div a{
    width:45%;
    float:right;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: as u see in image how can i get that design

Comment: It's not hard to do. use google developer tools (Inspect Element) to see what this page is doing to have a such style

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is breaking because you are not clearing your floating elements.  [This](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) is a good article all about floats.  However you don't need to float your button you can apply the following CSS to fix your layout issues

```
.div div {
    /* Remove old styles */
    text-align: right;
}

.div div a {
    /* Remove old styles */
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uru40nx/).
What actually broke your design was the absolute positioning.
I also added a min-width to the container-div, because otherwise it looks really creepy at a certain point.

```css
.div{
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width:22%;
    min-width:200px;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    border: solid 0 #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #CCC;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #CCC;
    
}
.div img{
    width:100%;
    height:180px;
}
.div h1{
    display:block;
    margin: 5px;
    font: 300 1.2em Roboto,Arial,Helvetica !important;
}
.div div{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    padding:9px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    text-align:right;
    border-top:solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="div">
    <img src="dual.png"/>
    <h1>How to take Snapshot in android Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.x</h1>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a></div>
</div>
```